# does aws sqs takes in consideration message attributes / system attributes in consideration when content based deduplication is enabled?

Tags: amazon-web-services, message-queue, amazon-sqs, aws-sqs-fifo

I am working on a project using aws sqs, i want to use content based deduplication for fifo queues but i couldnt find in the documentation if sqs considers message attributes and message system attributes as "**Content**" or no.

Comment: Message attributes are not included in the hash calculation. See it more here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/fifo-message-dedup.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after a search, and trying duplicating messages with different message system attributes, i found that indeed :

sqs does consider message attributes and message system attributes as "Content"